# Cannot access folders shared on the second hdd

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, samba, mountpoint

I have two folders shared using samba. One folder is in `/home/y` directory on the ssd and the second one on the second hdd mounted as `/media/y/hdd`. I can access the first, but I've got the message `Unable to mount location Failed to mount Windows share: Permission denied` when I try to access this folder from the same computer. I created these two folders and shared the in the same way in two minutes difference.

Here are the lines from fstab:

```
UUID=78e56d23-f01c-446b-a414-fe35618ddc6b /home          ext4    defaults,commit=120        0       2
UUID=e0b32ed6-51db-4f24-a4ab-706bd8d68922 /media/y/hdd   ext4    defaults        0       2
```

Here are the permissions for mount points:

```
drwxr-xr-x 107 y    y    12288 бер  2 19:26 y
drwxr-xr-x 26 y y 4096 вер 22  2014 hdd
```

Here are the permissions for shared directories:

```
drwxrwxrwx   3 y    y        4096 бер  1 17:33 test
drwxrwxrwx 2 y y      4096 бер  2 18:01 test2
```

Here is the output from `sudo net usershare info --long`

```
[test]
path=/home/y/test
comment=
usershare_acl=Everyone:F,
guest_ok=y

[test2]
path=/media/y/hdd/test2
comment=
usershare_acl=Everyone:F,
guest_ok=y
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem,then I mount my 2nd drive in home folder:

```
UUID=e0b32ed6-51db-4f24-a4ab-706bd8d68922 /home/user/hdd   ext4    defaults        0       2
```

That fixed my problem, I hope it helps.